# Date and Time conversion to hours and minutes

Tags: sql, oracle, data-conversion

In SQL developer, I substracted two `timestamp` columns which gave me the difference.

```
Select (created_dt_1 - created_dt_2) as delivery_time
from order;

DELIVERY_TIME
+02 05:12:30.651000
```

The output is saying it took 2 days and 5 hours and 12 minutes and 30 seconds.  However, I want it to be in hours and minutes only.  I was thinking about using extract to take the days and multiply by 24 hours from created_dt_1 and created_dt_2 then using extract again for hours and minutes and finally adding them all up.

However, I would like to know if there is a function or more efficient way of converting the 'delivery_time' into hours and minutes.

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking about using extract to take the days and multiply by 24 hours from created_dt_1 and created_dt_2 then using extract again for hours and minutes and finally adding them all up.

If you only want the time in minutes then:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC((CAST(created_dt_1 AS DATE) - CAST(created_dt_2 AS DATE)) * 24 * 60)
         AS delivery_time_minutes
FROM   orders;
```

If you want it as hours and minutes then:

```sql
SELECT (EXTRACT(DAY FROM delivery_time) * 24
         + EXTRACT(HOUR FROM delivery_time)) || ' hours '
         || EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM delivery_time) || ' minutes'
         AS delivery_time
FROM   (
  SELECT (created_dt_1 - created_dt_2) AS delivery_time
  FROM   orders
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a641fb8d9048d56a0d27ee98e77b2663)*